# How to find out maximum points possible from a directed acyclic graph?

Tags: graph

Sorry the title was no good. I am new to graph algorithms.

I'm stuck with a problem for several days. If all the nodes of a directed acyclic graph are weighted, while the weight can be negative, how can I find out a set for which the sum of the weights is maximum?

for example, we have a graph of 5 nodes-

- node 1 : weight 30, has a edges directed to node 4
- node 2 : weight 25, has edges directed to nodes 4,5
- node 3 : weight -65, no edges from it
- node 4 : weight -20, edge to node 5
- node 5 : weight 2, no edge from it

while finding out the maximum points, say, if node 1 is chosen, node 4 and as well as 5 must be chosen(as they are directly/indirectly adjacent from node 1).

so maximum point we can have is-
(30-20+2)+(25)=37

for node 1 and descendant 4,5, and then for node 2(node 4,5 not considered anymore)

I hope I made my problem clear. Can anybody tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not entirely clear.  The objective is to choose a set of *starting* nodes, such that the sum of the weights of those starting nodes and *all additional nodes reachable from that starting set* is maximum?

Comment: No it's not a homework. I tried to solve a graph relation problem, found out the SCC's of the graph and had to apply this on those connected sets.

Comment: @Jeffrey Hantin : No you can choose any combination of the verteces, while making sure summation of the points is maximum.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly... What you want is to find a node that maximizes the sum of values that that node can reach.

Here is some psuedo-code that would do this for you

```
def maxVertex(Vertices):
    for vertex in reversed_topological_sorted(Vertices):
         vertex.value = vertex.weight
         if vertex.neighbors:
                vertex.value += sum( other_vertex.value for other_vetrex in vertex.neighbors )

     return max(Vertices,key=lambda vertex: vertex.value)
```

Comment: Actually, it looks to me like he means the set of possibly multiple starting nodes, without counting any reachable node twice.

Comment: Yes that's what i want to do. Actually the maximum point obtained this way should be enough for the problem.